# Clear the database on the server when the app is closing

Tags: android

I want to clear the table on the server side  to delete all data related to specific mac address when the user closes the application. Therefore, I am trying to start the Intentservice class when the onDestroy() is invoked. Currently when I close the app the `onHandleIntent` is not being invoked and nothing happens.

**MainActivity class**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    System.out.println("JsonObject" + jsonObject);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            ClearTable.class);
    intent2.putExtra("json_mac", json);
    startService(intent2);
      }
```

**onDestroy in the MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();

     JsonObject  jsonObject = new  JsonObject();
     jsonObject.addProperty("mac", macAddress);

    System.out.println("JsonObject" + jsonObject);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            ClearTable.class);
    intent2.putExtra("json_mac", json);
    startService(intent2);
```

}

IntentService class:

```
public class ClearTable extends IntentService{

    public ClearTable() {
        super("IntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_mac");
            System.out.println("xyz The output of : doInBackground "
                    + jSONString);
            URL myUrl = new URL(
                    "https://serverside-apple.rhcloud.com/webapi/test");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();             
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();             
            System.out.println("xyz The output of getResponsecode: "
             + conn.getResponseCode());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".ClearTable" />
```

Comment: `try to call 'super.onDestroy()' at the end.`

Answer (score 0):

make an action(i.e function) on your server side controller(which is handling request) to clear tables which you want to clear and call it via sending request through url(that includes values instructing to call that action)

Comment: But the Problem is where can I place the code in the Android app  to call this Action and how to know when the app is being closed.

Comment: instead of putting it onDestroy, also call it on exit button(or option).. and also create a dialog to which pops to confirm exit and on that positive action call it..which maximizes the chance to call that function.. relying on action..


but in my best advice call it onStart() instead on closing call it onStart()

or you could use on start and destory..just check if data exist or not ..if exist then call :)

Answer (score 0):

first: make sure you really cloase your app while testing, i.e. pressing the home-button is only pausing the app "onPause()" and later "onStop()", but not closing it "onDestroy()". Have a look at the graphic at the middle of this page [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (scroll down till you hit the image)

for really closing it, you need to press your multitasking button (on current android phones there is usually a back and a multitasking button next to the home button) and swipe your app from screen.

second:   try calling super.onDestroy() at last

> @Override
>
> protected void onDestroy() {
>
> your code goes here
>
> super.onDestroy();
>
> }

Comment: but I dont want to clear the tables when the app goes in the Background. And it is not matter whether I place my code after `super.onDestroy();` or before.

Comment: the only other thing i see, at the moment is, that you call ` super("IntentService");` instead of `super("ClearTable");`

Comment: on my project i put a `Log.d("mydebug", "onDestroy()");` in the onDestroy-method and it was there everytime i manually closed the app on Android 5.0. That way we can see, if it is the onDestroy() not being called, or something else

Comment: I have this line `System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onDestroy().");` in the onDestroy() and is being invoked but the Problem the Intentent Service class is being started. I think the onDestroy() does not allow  this kind of action.

Comment: sorry, did not see it. could you try, if it still shows up in the log, if you put it at the end of onDestroy() ?  or a different idea: create/prepare the intent somewhere in your app, while it is running, and place only `startService(..)` in `onDestroy()`

Comment: Yes I can see this line `System.out.println("ABC MainActivity onDestroy()."); `  when I close the app.  I placed the code in onDestroy() for starting the IntentService inside  onPause() and the IntentService is being invoked.

Comment: I think obDestroy() does not allow to start Service or activity inside it.

Comment: i got one more idea you could try: instead of ServiceIntent use a Thread.  create and start a Thread somewhere in you app, but let it do nothing, but Thread.wait(). in onDestroy() you use Thread.interrupt() which will then make the thread continue and will do your cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) also says the `onDestroy()` call is not guaranteed, so if you want to make sure that your function is called you need to implement `onPause()` method (even tough this will cause that your data will be deleted more often, but this is the only guaranteed way.)

Comment: The Problem wih `onPause()` and `onStop()` that the tables are being cleared even when the app goes in the Background or when the activity is being changed.

Comment: `As the documentation also says the onDestroy() call is not guaranteed` call is not guarantee when `While app is in background and OS kills the app process to free memory`. Pressing back to exit app will always call the onDestroy().

Comment: My other idea would be that your server send a request to the phone and if the phone not answers than you can delete the data... :/ or just delete it after 5-10-15 minutes